# Creating a view of all facilties a room has

Tags: sql, oracle

I have several tables in a SQL database whice store some information about a hotel. I want to create a view where I can see what facilities a floor has. This my first table:

```
CREATE TABLE FLOORNO (
    FLOORNUMBER NUMBER(1),
    ROOMTYPENAME VARCHAR(255),
    BASICPRICE NUMBER(2)
);
```

and a second table which describes the facilities a floor has:

```
CREATE TABLE FACILITIES (
    FLOORNUMBER NUMBER(1) NOT NULL,
    FACILITY VARCHAR(60)
);
```

This is my create view statement:

```
CREATE VIEW "PRICES" AS
    SELECT fl.FLOORNUMBER, fa.FACILITY
    FROM FLOORNO fL
    INNER JOIN FACILITY fa
        ON fl.FLOORNUMBER = fa.FLOORNUMBER;
```

It creates the view but when I ask it to display the information it says "no rows selected" and I cant figure out why. Can anyone point out what's going wrong here?

Comment: Your `create table` statements do not match the tables referenced in your query.

Comment: Yh I posted the wrong command, have updated it now.

Comment: Have you considered the possibility it's not giving you rows because, well, there are no rows? What do you do to fill the tables? What does `SELECT *` on both yield?

Comment: @bancqm Presume that both `FLOORNO` and `FACILITIES` are having matching `FLOORNUMBER` values. And replace `INNER JOIN` with `LEFT OUTER JOIN`

Comment: "*Can anyone point out what's going wrong here?". Yeah the data in the tables is different from what you think it is. Either the tables a empty or the `floornumber` keys don't match.

Comment: You could use a `LEFT JOIN` or even `FULL OUTER JOIN` to determine whether there are non-matching values for `floornumber`

Comment: @JeroenMostert The tables are filed with data using the Insert into command, I didn't include that as there's a lot of data there

Comment: @DavidFaber just tried that, also dosen't work.

Comment: You don't need to give or study all the data. `SELECT DISTINCT FLOORNUMBER` on both tables would do -- this will allow you to immediately gauge what's what in terms of joining. Also, simply executing the view query under an account that can certainly see all data will allow you to verify it's not an issue with permissions/your front-end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking to your create table you are using wrong table name  use FACILITIES and not FACILITY

```
CREATE VIEW PRICES AS
SELECT fl.FLOORNUMBER, fa.FACILITY
FROM FLOORNO fL
INNER JOIN FACILITIES fa
    ON fl.FLOORNUMBER = fa.FLOORNUMBER;
```